# Frequencies by date

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows. each case ha a date and each have four status variables with yes/no ansvers. There are also cases with missing variables.

A sample data is below

```
 ID     Date         Status 1         Status 2           Status 3                  Status 4
    1  2021/03/11         Yes              N/A                 N/A                       N/A
    2  2021/03/11         No               N/A                 N/A                       N/A
    3  2021/03/11         Yes              Yes                 Yes                       Yes 
    4  2021/03/11         and so on...
```

What I wanna have is daily distributions of answers. I want to see bar graphs of how many missing, 'Yes' and 'No' daily.

To sum up, I need daily frequencies of status variables in a data frame.

```
xtabs(~Date+'Status 1', data = dat)
```

creates what I want for each like:

Date, count of yes, and count of no.

When I write:

```
status_1 <- as.data.frame(xtabs(~Date+'Status 1', data = dat)
```

then there are two rows for each date.

How can I merge two answers for each four by date into one data frame?

Comment: I did very long transformations for this but I believe there is a smarter and shorter choice! First I use status_1 <- as.data.frame(xtabs(~Date+'Status 1', data = dat)  as I stated below and created separate four databases for status variables. I did a fifth for date. Then I divided each state variable into two for the two choices. Then I matched 8 separate status dataframes into one matching on date. Quite long.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here is a faster way for your problem. By transforming the dataset into longformat with `pivot_longer` you  can calculate the frequencies in a few lines of code with the `tidyverse` packages.

**Example Data**

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(lubridate)

dat <- data.frame(ID = 1:20,
                 Date = rep(c(ymd(20200311),
                               ymd(20200312),
                               ymd(20200313), 
                               ymd(20200314)), 5),
                 `Status 1` = sample(c("Yes", "No", NA), 20, replace = T),
                 `Status 2` = sample(c("Yes", "No", NA), 20, replace = T),
                 `Status 3` = sample(c("Yes", "No", NA), 20, replace = T),
                 `Status 4` = sample(c("Yes", "No", NA), 20, replace = T),
                 check.names = F)
```

**Code**

```
dat2 <- dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID,  Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Date, name, value) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

head(dat2)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Date       name     value     n
  <date>     <chr>    <fct> <int>
1 2020-03-11 Status 1 Yes       2
2 2020-03-11 Status 1 NA        3
3 2020-03-11 Status 2 No        1
4 2020-03-11 Status 2 Yes       2
5 2020-03-11 Status 2 NA        2
6 2020-03-11 Status 3 Yes       2
```

**Example Plot**

```
ggplot(dat2) +
  geom_col(aes(x = name, y = n, fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(.~Date)
```

[image]